# Combine Activity and fragment into a class android

Tags: android, json, android-activity, fragment

I want to ask, 
I have 2 classes:

```
   1. an activity class (to get data from json)
   2. a fragment class (not to do something)
```

and I want to get data from json of activity via fragment class.
Can be combine Activity and Fragment in a class ? and how to do ?

I combined activity and fragment in a Fragment class, I have used a GridView to get data and display
JSON, execute the AsyncTask in the this Fragment

***This is my code after updated 25/10:***

```
public class FeedBackFragment extends Fragment {

ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

MyAdapter adapter;
JSONArray manufacturers = null;

// manufacturers JSON url
private static final String URL_MANUFACTURERS ="MYURL";

public FeedBackFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feedback_gridview_manufacturer, container, false);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity(), manufacturersList));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // on selecting a single manufacturer
            // CategoryCarActivity will be launched to show category car inside the manufacturer
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CategoryCarActivity.class);

            // send manufacturer id to activity to get list of cars under that manufacturer
            String manufacturer_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer_id)).getText().toString();
            i.putExtra("manufacturer_id", manufacturer_id);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // manufacturersList = new ArrayList<>();
    new LoadAllManufacturers().execute();
}


class LoadAllManufacturers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all manufacturers
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    // List<POJOManufacturer> listData = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList)
    {
        // this.context = context;
        this.manufacturersList = arrayList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (manufacturersList != null)
            return manufacturersList.size();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i)
    {
        if (manufacturersList != null)
            return manufacturersList.get(i);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i)
    {
        if (manufacturersList != null)
            return manufacturersList.get(i).hashCode();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.iconName = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }           
        holder.name.setText(this.manufacturersList.get(i).getClass().getName());
        // holder.iconName.setImageResource(this.manufacturersList.get(i).image);

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView name;
        ImageView iconName;
    }        
   }
 }
```

I have updated and added: manufacturerList = new ArrayList<>. everything seem is better, and it happen some issues in ***getView()*** method, 
I have try and it's only display with 7 empty items in gridview, and not display content and image

So How fill data from Adapter into Gridview?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Please show your code and what you've attempted, though

Comment: Though, beware, this sounds like a repost of the previous question you had.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066514/implement-activity-in-fragment-android

Comment: Hi Cricket_007, I try to explain for you understand my question

Comment: I will post again my source code here

Comment: I posted several useful comments on the other post. I'm still suggesting Retrofit. I also suggest downloading the JSON into the Fragment directly rather than passing it between the Activity and the Fragment.

Comment: If you have the exact same code... Don't extend ListActivity. Make a GridView in the Activity. Done.... You've combined the layouts. What is the problem with that?

Comment: as you have reviewed my source code in:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066514/implement-activity-in-fragment-android. 
 My problem is: I want to load all data of ManufacturerActivity and display data in HomeFragment

Comment: Then move the AsyncTask it to its own file. Execute the AsyncTask in the Fragment, and populate the Adapter.

Comment: Ok I will try right now and back to you :)

Comment: Hi Cricket_007, I have try and it has happened some errors, if I want to convert ManufacturerActivity to ManufacturerFragment, is it ok ? or do you have better solution for me ?

Comment: You can't convert an Activity to a Fragment. You need an Activity to display a Fragment.

Comment: Hi Cricket_007, I have updated my new source code base on your advance, but Im facing an error, I have updated my source code as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> constructor ManufacturerFragment in class ManufacturerFragment cannot be applied to given types;

`gridView.setAdapter()` takes an **adapter**, not a `Fragment`

And `new ManufacturerFragment()` doesn't accept an `Context`.

I am not really sure why you think you need to create a `new ManufacturerFragment` within the Fragment class you already are in. Did you mean to do `gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity()))`?

Also, your `manufacturersList` needs to be loaded into that adapter, so you'll need to figure that out.

And you need to use `getActivity()` instead of `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` in most places.

Then, you should only call `new LoadAllManufacturers().execute();` in either `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated`, not both. Otherwise, you're running two AsyncTasks.

Then, `onPostExecute` already runs on the UI thread, no need to use `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...`

Once you do figure out how to put that ArrayList into the Adapter class, you'll want to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` within `onPostExecute` to tell the adapter to refresh the data, thereby updating the GridView to display the data.

Comment: Hi Cricket_007, I have updated new source code as above, can you review and support me ?

Comment: @luongkhanh You do not have `manufacturersList = new ArrayList<>` anywhere in your code. You have a `null` list in the AsyncTask. Your error is a NullpointerException

Comment: @Hi Cricket_007, I have updated my code, please review it above

Comment: You should create new posts with new problems. You seem to have fixed all problems with the initial answer I have provided, therefore the recommended action here is to accept this post, then ask a [mcve] in a new post.

Comment: Hi Cricket_007, I have solved the problem, thank you !

Comment: Glad to hear. By the way, if you want to notify someone, you can use `@username`.